# ViewModel is not called in Second fragment when viewModel list is updated from First fragment listview adapter class

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm

Basically i have a viewModel which should be used in Second fragment to observe a list.
For that i made the viewModel like this.

```
public class DetailsViewModel extends ViewModel {
MutableLiveData<List<ItemModal>> childList ;
private DataSnapshot dataSnapshot;
List<ItemModal> tempList;

public DetailsViewModel() {
    childList = new MutableLiveData<>();
}


public void setList(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    this.dataSnapshot = dataSnapshot;
    convertList();
}

public void convertList(){

    try {
        tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        childList = new MutableLiveData<>();
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            ItemModal itemModal = new ItemModal();
            itemModal.setItemType(this.dataSnapshot.getKey());
            itemModal.setItemContent(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            itemModal.setItemName(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            tempList.add(itemModal);
        }
        childList.setValue(tempList);
    }
    catch (Exception c){
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public MutableLiveData<List<ItemModal>> getList(){
    return this.childList;
}

}
```

And and my Second fragment class i called this viewModel like this. Which is never called.

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, container, false);
    recyclerViewDetails = view.findViewById(R.id.recycleDetails);


    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DetailsViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getList().observe(this,  new Observer<List<ItemModal>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<ItemModal> itemModals) {

                AdapterDetailsRecycle adapterDetailsRecycle = new AdapterDetailsRecycle(getContext(), itemModals);
                recyclerViewDetails.setAdapter(adapterDetailsRecycle);

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

I am setting the viewModel's list from an list adapter which belongs to  First fragment .like that

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_main,parent,false);
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtCatName);
    ItemModal itemModal = itemModalList.get(position);
    textView.setText(itemModal.getItemType());
    detailsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity)context).get(DetailsViewModel.class);
    final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = itemModal.getChilds();
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            detailsViewModel.setList(dataSnapshot);
            ((MainActivity)context).changeFragment(new DetailsFragment());

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

So the problem is that the list of viewModel is updated successfully from the list adapter on an item's click which relates to First fragment. But the viewModel is not called in the Second fragment where it is called to use the list.

Any Help would be strongly appropriated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because you are reinstantiating viewmodel in second fragment. Its not the same instance which you have in first fragment. If you want to make it work like this use SharedViewModel.